# Access an object from another dart file

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an object `Students` on `Group1.dart` file

```
   class Group1 extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
    Students('Alex','Thomas')
    //...
    }
    //My Object
    Students (String a, string b){
      //....
      }
        }
```

And I create `Group2.dart` and `Group3.dart`.

My question, how can I access object `Students` from `Group1` ?

Like that

```
class Group2 extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //...
        Students('Alex','Thomas')
        //...
        }
            }
```

I tried create `Students.dart`

```
class ModalStudents {
String _a, _b;
ModalStudents (this._a, this._b);
String get a => _a;
String get b =>_b;}
```

but I don't know what next.

Comment: you can read this post : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, then you want to share "state". In this case your Students object. There are many state management patterns like:

- ScopedModel
- Redux
- BLoC
- ...

Then you can do whatever you want with your Students in every class :)

Other scenario: Your Widget Group2 is in Group1. Then you can just pass it as parameter ;)

Yours Glup3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scoped_model package

You want the model to extend Model

```
class StudentModel extends Model {
                 ...
    }
```

In group 1

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ScopedModel<StudentModel>(
      model: StudentModel(),
```

In group 2

```
ScopedModelDescendant<StudentModel>(
              builder: (context, child, model){
                   ...
}
```

Inside the descendant you can access the properties of the model like such: model.a, model.b